# What is a BPMS?

Tags: java, .net, business-process-management

What is BPMS? and when to go for BPMS? is there any free tools for .net or java? is there any plug-in available for eclipse?

Comment: What is a BMPS? http://www.google.com/search?q=bpms

Comment: Homework indeed. Very tempted to put in a "let me google that for you" link - but to be helpful - https://tallyfy.com/guides/business-process-management-bpm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short for Business Process Management System or Software and basically is a tool for very high level modelling how the business will do whatever they do and how automation tools are integrated.

These things are typically huge and composed of a big collection of tools and infrastructure stuff. Eclipse based tooling may be a part of that, but it is much larger than just a plugin.

If you want to dip your toe in these waters you might look at JBoss Tools which has support for JBPM and Webservices which is a workflow package and the infrastructure which is usually core to these systems.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

As Peter said, BPMS is a huge topic. To get an idea of its scope, check out IBM's home page on it here: http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/category/bpm-software

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Activiti](http://activiti.org) BPMN 2.0 engine. It is still in beta but a project everybody interested in BPM software should know about. It is implemented in Java and an Eclipse plugin also will be part of the set of tools.

Answer (score 0):

Stardust, the Eclipse Process Manager,is a comprehensive and mature BPMS which is part of the  Eclipse release train since the Kepler release. With over 2.5M lines of code and 726 person years Stardust is the largest Open Source BPMS.

As opposed to many Java-centric BPMS, Stardust also provides proven .NET integration capabilities on servcie and UI level.
The process modeler is avalibe for Eclipse or purely browser-based. The runtime environment can be used from inside Eclipse (WTP integration) or standalone (maven build).

Please see http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/ for more details.

Best regards

Rob

Answer (score -2):

[BPM - Business Process Management](https://kissflow.com/bpm/top-10-features-for-business-process-management-systems/) is a systematic approach to streamline an organization’s process to make it efficient and  effective, to suit the changing environment around.